# In javascript, is there a way to turn a url into a data-url?

Tags: javascript, data-url

I would like to take a regular old url and turn it into a data url that encodes the entire file.  Is there a way to do that?

Alternately, the question could be: is there a way to get a `File` object for a given url? (because then I could use a `FileReader` to call `readAsDataURL`).

Comment: The file you are referencing (assuming via HTTP) would need to already be base-64 encoded unless it is just an image.

Comment: You would need to be able to download it from the client (e.g. with `XMLHttpRequest`), which means you're subject to the SOP. Or are you talking about doing this server-side?

Comment: @Diodeus I am only doing this for images right now.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the info.  I'll have to think on that.

Comment: @Bergi, XMLHttpRequest worked perfectly!  Thank you for that.  If you want to re-write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> take a regular old url and turn it into a data url that encodes the entire file

…means that you need to get the data from the file. This can be done by using an `XMLHttpRequest` (as long as the URL points to your [own domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). Then take the loaded data, pass it to [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.btoa), and concatenate it with the response's [`Content-Type`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) header.